# Magento 2 - Get number of results on current search page when including a block

Tags: php, magento2

I'm trying to access getResultCount() in \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result

I have the following block created.

```
class GetSearch extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_pageTitle;
    protected $_result;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title $pageTitle,
        \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result $result)
    {
        $this->_pageTitle = $pageTitle;  
        $this->_result = $result;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->_pageTitle->getShort();
    }
     public function getSearchResults()
    {
        return $this->_result->getResultCount();
    }

}
```

When I call `<?=$block->getSearchResults();?>`

I receive the following error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getLoadedProductCollection() on boolean

I think I'm going about this the wrong way and somehow need to access the current object that contains the search results but I'm a little lost.

What's the best method of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the answer and it is to use the QueryFactory to return the instance of the Query model.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future!

```
class GetSearch extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_pageTitle;
    protected $_query;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title $pageTitle,
        \Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory $query)
    {
        $this->_pageTitle = $pageTitle;  
        $this->_query = $query;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->_pageTitle->getShort();
    }

    public function getSearchResults()
    {

       return $this->_query->get()->getNumResults();
    }

}
```